# What's wrong in this elasticsearch query, how to do multiple filters?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I want to run 2 filters for the data. The data should be in a time range and should have a severity of particular type. I am getting an empty response.

```
{"query": {
    "bool":{
    "filter":[
        {"term": {
            "severity.keyword":"Critical"
            }   
        },
        {"range": {
            "start_time": {
            "gte": "now-1d/d",
            "lte": "now/d"
            }
         }
       }
    ]
}}}
```

Here's a sample doc:

```
        "_index": "historical_alerts-000035",

        "_type": "_doc",

        "_id": "L3KCe4IB5gpwX0ta7_iA",

        "_score": 0,

        "_source": {

          "stack": "M2",

          "organization": "Terminals",

          "data_center": "notset",

          "element_name": "dshdn4n34n34n3",

          "instance_name": "",

          "class_name": "Multimedia VSAT",

          "nmd": "notset",

          "dynamic_app_name": "Internal",

          "policy_name": "App Exception",

          "severity": "Minor",

          "user_id": "undef",

          "start_time": 1659922229000,

          "stop_time": 1659924089000,

          "clear_duration": 1860,

          "event_id": "63964892",

          "event_text": "App: 58, Snippet: 53 reported a collection problem (Explanation: SNMP error returned)",

          "value": null,

          "user_acked": null,

          "user_del": null,

          "ack_time": 0

        }

      }
```

And yes this doc has severity as Minor but I have tried that filter as well in combination with date but got no results back.

Here's the mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"
      ],
      "dynamic_templates": [],
      "date_detection": true,
      "numeric_detection": false,
      "properties": {
        "ack_time": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "class_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "index_options": "docs",
          "norms": false
        },
        "clear_duration": {
          "type": "float",
          "ignore_malformed": false,
          "coerce": true
        },
        "data_center": {
          "type": "text",
          "index_options": "docs",
          "norms": false
        },
        "dynamic_app_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "element_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "event_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "event_text": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "instance_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "nmd": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "organization": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "policy_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "severity": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "stack": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "start_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "stop_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "user_acked": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user_del": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you execute this query?

Comment: Can you show a document that you think should match? and also the mapping of those two fields if possible

Comment: @ishanc this comment ^^

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff  No error. Let me post the response here

{

  "took": 4,

  "timed_out": false,

  "_shards": {

    "total": 24,

    "successful": 24,

    "skipped": 23,

    "failed": 0

  },

  "hits": {

    "total": {

      "value": 0,

      "relation": "eq"

    },

    "max_score": null,

    "hits": []

  }

}

Comment: there is no problem in your query the result is empty cause you have no doc that match the filters  `severity.keyword":"Critical"`  and `"start_time"` between specified range

Comment: @Val I have added a sample doc and mapping

Comment: @to_data Thanks for responding but I know what my data is.

Comment: I do not see any issue with the query , Can you try with severity":"Critical" as it is text in mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "severity" field is a "text" type that generates the "minor" token (value of the example you sent). You use the filter with the "term" clause (this clause requires the exact match of the term), ie "minor" != "Minor". To work you would have to map the field "severity" as a keyword as well.

For your query to work without changing the mapping you can do this:

```
"filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "severity": "minor"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "start_time": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: What puzzles me is that this still works when just one filter is applied.

{"query": {
   "bool":{
    "filter":[
     {"term": {
      "severity.keyword":"Critical"
      }   
     }
    ]
}}}